# Embed a CodePen into a React framework site

Tags: reactjs, embed, codepen

I have been building a basic React webapp and today I thought it would be fun to put together a page to showcase a #30daycodechallenge project I have undertaken (day twos challenge is to get day ones challenge to load on my site).

Here is the code for the page in question:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Coding extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p
                    class="codepen" data-height="265" data-theme-id="default" data-default-tab="css,result" data-user="isaac-tait" data-slug-hash="BaywrNQ" 
                    style="height: 265px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" 
                    data-pen-title="Ying Yang">
                    <span>
                        See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/isaac-tait/pen/BaywrNQ">Ying Yang</a> by Isaac Tait (<a href="https://codepen.io/isaac-tait">@isaac-tait</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.
                    </span>
                </p>
                    <script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Coding
```

Basically a boilerplate Codepen HTML embed copy and paste. However, the issue I am running into is that the page is showing up but the Codepen is not. [Here](https://mountaintopcoding.com/#/Coding) is a link to the page in question (FYI - it is in its infancy right now).

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two things that helped fix the issue I was having.

1) I had defined my new component (the page I was featuring my CodePens on) but I had not used it within the NavBar component. I discovered the error when I ran `npm start`

2) I was reading [this](https://blog.soshace.com/create-a-simple-pos-with-react-node-and-mongodb-0-initial-setup-frontend-and-backend/) tutorial and came across the VS Code plugin *html to jsx* when I converted the Codepen embed into JSX it appeared in my browser window within my now functioning component.

Moral of the story: Always test your environment :D